# R: Calculating Conditional Probabilities With DPLYR

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset - this data represents students (e.g. id = 1, id = 2, id = 3) who took an exam at different dates, and the result that they got (0 = pass, 1 = fail).

```
library(data.table)

  my_data = data.table( structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), results = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1), date_exam_taken = structure(c(12889, 12943, 15445, 15528, 
17840, 10623, 10680, 11186, 11971, 12826, 13744, 13805, 14904, 
15089, 15815, 16883, 17511, 17673, 11500, 12743, 14906, 15675, 
16774), class = "Date"), exam_number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 23L), class = "data.frame"))

> head(my_data)
   id results date_exam_taken exam_number
1:  1       0      2005-04-16           1
2:  1       0      2005-06-09           2
3:  1       1      2012-04-15           3
4:  1       1      2012-07-07           4
5:  1       1      2018-11-05           5
6:  2       0      1999-02-01           1
```

Using the following code in R, I was able to count the number of "3 exam transitions" - that is, I was able to count the number of times each student experienced :

- "pass, pass, pass"
- "pass, pass, fail"
- etc
- "fail, fail, fail"

The R code looks something like this:

```
my_data$current_exam = shift(my_data$results, 0)
my_data$prev_exam = shift(my_data$results, 1)
my_data$prev_2_exam = shift(my_data$results, 2)

# Count the number of exam results for each record
out <- my_data[!is.na(prev_exam), .(tally = .N), by = .(id, current_exam, prev_exam, prev_2_exam)]

out = na.omit(out)

> head(out)
    id current_exam prev_exam prev_2_exam tally
 1:  1            1         0           0     1
 2:  1            1         1           0     1
 3:  1            1         1           1     1
 4:  2            0         1           1     3
```

**Now, I want to calculate the probability of the student pass/failing the current exam, conditional on the results of the previous exam and the second previous exam.**

I thought the best way to do this was to first perform an aggregation:

```
library(dplyr)
agg = out %>% group_by(current_exam, prev_exam, prev_2_exam) %>% summarise(total = sum(tally))

> agg
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   current_exam, prev_exam [3]
  current_exam prev_exam prev_2_exam total
         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <int>
1            0         1           0     1
2            0         1           1     4
3            1         0           0     1
4            1         0           1     5
5            1         1           0     4
6            1         1           1     6
```

**From here, I am trying to look for an efficient way to calculate all conditional probabilities** (i.e. P(current exam = 0 | prev_exam = 0 & prev_2_exam = 0)). These conditional probabilities should be aggregated for the group and should represent the conditional probability (of some event happening) of any student within the population.

I figured out how to do this manually for a single example:

```
# prob (current = 1, given  prev = 1, 2nd_prev =1
p1 = agg[ agg$current_exam == 1 & agg$prev_exam == 1 & agg$prev_2_exam == 1,]
p2 = agg[ agg$current_exam == 0 & agg$prev_exam == 1 & agg$prev_2_exam == 1,]

final_prob_1_1_1 = sum(p1$total)/(sum(p1$total) + sum(p2$total))
```

**But is there some easier way to do this, for all possible combinations? Is there some DPLYR function that can "look back" and count all combinations until the second last column and calculate all the conditional probabilities?**

In the end - I am looking to get an output with 8 rows that looks something like this:

```
 second_prev_prev      current_exam          probs
                11            1              prob1
                11            0              prob2
                10            1              prob3
                10            0              prob4
                01            1              prob5
                01            0              prob6
                00            1              prob7
                00            0              prob8
```

Thanks!

**Note:** My attempt - is this correct?

```
# my own attempt - I don't think this is correct because in row 5, row 6 - the probabilities sum to a value greater than 1? 
> agg %>%
     group_by(prev_exam, prev_2_exam) %>%
     mutate(probability = total / sum(total))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   prev_exam, prev_2_exam [4]
  current_exam prev_exam prev_2_exam total probability
         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <int>       <dbl>
1            0         1           0     1         0.2
2            0         1           1     4         0.4
3            1         0           0     1         1  
4            1         0           1     5         1  
5            1         1           0     4         0.8
6            1         1           1     6         0.6
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: @ akrun: i showed an example of the expected output - 3 columns, 8 rows?

Comment: Your statement says `I don't think this is correct because in row 5, row 6 - the probabilities sum to a value greater than 1`  I was thinking this related to `cube` or `rollup`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data |> 
  arrange(id, exam_number) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(counter = 1:n(),
         results_lag = lag(results, n = 1),
         exams_passed = results + results_lag,
         prob = lag(exams_passed / counter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the probability that a student passes (or fails) an exam given their previous two exam results. I first create the lags (exam_1 = previous exam, exam_2 = the one before that) and then aggregate (as you did).

```
group_by(my_data, id) |>
  mutate(exam_1=lag(results, n=1),  
         exam_2=lag(results, n=2)) |>
  filter(!is.na(exam_2)) |>
  group_by(id, exam_2, exam_1) |>
  summarise(passed=sum(results==1),   # the number of times student passed the current exam 
            n=n(), .groups='drop') |> # the number of times these events occurred
  mutate(prob.pass=passed/n,
         prob.fail=1-prob.pass)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 8 × 7
     id exam_2 exam_1 passed     n prob.pass prob.fail
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <int> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      0      0      1     1      1         0   
2     1      0      1      1     1      1         0   
3     1      1      1      1     1      1         0   
4     2      0      1      3     4      0.75      0.25
5     2      1      0      3     3      1         0   
6     2      1      1      2     4      0.5       0.5 
7     3      1      0      1     1      1         0   
8     3      1      1      1     2      0.5       0.5
```

---

You can verify these results just by looking at the original data. For student 1, there are only 3 possibilities (fail/fail, fail/pass, pass/pass), each occurring once, and for each of these, they passed the current exam. So, the probabilities are all 1. For student 3, there are only 2 possibilities: (pass/fail, n=1) or (pass/pass, n=2) with probabilities 1 and 0.5, respectively. For student 2, there are 3 possibilities (fail/pass, pass/fail, pass/pass) and the probabilties are the number of times they passed the current exam (n=3,3,2) divided by the number of times the events occurred (n=4,3,4) giving probabilties of 0.75, 1, and 0.5.

All other possibilities didn't occur in your data, so you can assume the probabilities are 0 (or you can say that you don't have enough data to calculate them).

If you ignore the student, you get the following results:

```
  exam_2 exam_1 passed     n prob.pass prob.fail
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <int> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1      0      0      1     1     1         0    
2      0      1      4     5     0.8       0.2  
3      1      0      4     4     1         0    
4      1      1      4     7     0.571     0.429
```

Which says that, in a run of three exams, if a student fails the first (exam_2) but passes the second (exam_1), they are 80% likely to pass the third (passed). If they pass the first but fail the second, then they are 100% likely to pass the third. However, and this seems like an example of complacency, if they pass the first two, then they are only 57% likely to pass the third.