# Apply custom function that returns multiple values after dplyr::rowwise()

Tags: r, dplyr

I attempted to apply a custom function on each row using `dplyr::rowwose()` as below

```
library(dplyr)
dat = data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'C' = 1:3, 'D' = 1:3, 'M' = 1:3)
dat %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(c('A1', 'A2') = function(x) {c('A' + 5, 'D')})
```

So basically here, my custom function takes columns `A and D` and then perform some calculation and return a vector, which I want to append to the original data frame.

However above implementation is failing.

Can you please help with some insight how can I use `rowwise()` function to perform above calculation? Above example of applied function is fairly simple, however in my original case, such function is pretty complex. Also, I do not prefer to define that function stand alone basis, rather want to define on-the-fly within `mutate` to keep my code tidy.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Yes right. I just corrected my post

Comment: It makes sense to name the columns as `A1` and `D1` as these are creatd from 'A', 'D' respectively.  In addition `rowwise` is slow compared to vectorized operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to create a function that returns a `vector` or `list` or a `tibble`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
f1 <- function(x, y) tibble(A1 = x + 5, A2 = y + 1)
dat %>% 
   mutate(Anew = f1(A, D)) %>%
   unnest_wider(Anew)
# A tibble: 3 × 6
      A     C     D     M    A1    A2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     6     2
2     2     2     2     2     7     3
3     3     3     3     3     8     4
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to apply some generic function i.e. something like `dat %>% mutate(across(c(A, D), ~ function(xx) xx['A'] * [... some complex calculation with 'A' & 'D'], .names = '{str_c(.col, 1)}'))`

Comment: @BrianSmith If I understand your comment, you don't need to loop over both columns, Perhaps you can create a function, `f1 <- function(x, y) c(x + 5, y + 1)`

Comment: Thats perfect. Just one more question. Is it possible to define and apply `function(x, y) c(x + 5, y + 1)` within `mutate`, instead define it separately and then applying it within `mutate`?

Comment: @BrianSmith Does the update helps you.  It is not clear how your function works.  I tried to replicate by modifying the output returns as a `tibble` and then we can directly apply the function  to create a column and then use `unnest_wider`

Comment: @BrianSmith You don't need a function then i.e. `dat %>% 
   mutate(Anew =  tibble(A1 = A + 5, A2 = D + 1)) %>% unnest_wider(Anew)` should work as well.  But lambda functions can be created on the fly.  Although a lambda function makes sense when the function is one-liner instead of multiple statements

Comment: I agree. For this simple calculation, defining a function may be extra. But in my original case, I need to perform some complex calculation, so perform that calculation through some function would be convenient.

Comment: @BrianSmith You can have a lamdba function like `dat %>% 
   mutate(Anew =  (function(x, y) tibble(A1 = x + 5, A2 = y + 1))(A, D)) %>% unnest_wider(Anew)`

Comment: @ akrun : I have been working on this problem for a a few days (also related to dplyr) - can you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838616/r-calculating-conditional-probabilities-with-dplyr thanks!