# Apply dplyr::starts_with() with lambda function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

I have below implementation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat = data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'C_1' = 1:3, 'C_2' = 1:3, 'M' = 1:3)
```

Below works

```
dat %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Anew = list({function(x) c(x[1]^2, x[2] + 5, x[3] + 1)}(c(M, C_1, C_2)))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest_wider(Anew, names_sep = "")
```

However below does not work when I try find the column names using `dplyr::starts_with()`

```
dat %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Anew = list({function(x) c(x[1]^2, x[2] + 5, x[3] + 1)}(c(M, starts_with('C_'))))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest_wider(Anew, names_sep = "")
```

Any pointer on how to correctly apply `starts_with()` in this context will be very helpful.

PS : This is continuation from my earlier post [Apply custom function that returns multiple values after dplyr::rowwise()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844356/apply-custom-function-that-returns-multiple-values-after-dplyrrowwise#74844383)

Comment: What happens, when the number of `C_` columns are not equal to 2.  This seems to be similar to the case I showed i.e. `nm1 <- c(C_1 = 5, C_2 = 1); dat %>% mutate(across(starts_with("C_"), ~ .x + nm1[cur_column()], .names = "{.col}_new"))`

Comment: I have edited my original post to reflect my actual problem more closer

Comment: I guess you need `c_across` i.e. `dat %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Anew = list((function(x) c(x[1]^2, x[2] + 5, x[3] + 1))(c_across(starts_with("C_"))))) %>% unnest_wider(Anew, names_sep = "")`  Also, you need `C_3` in the data as the `x[3]` corresponds to the third column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wrap the `starts_with` in `c_across` and assuming there is a third column that starts with `C_`, then the lambda function on the fly would work

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
   mutate(Anew = list((function(x) c(x[1]^2, x[2] + 5, x[3] + 
      1))(c_across(starts_with("C_"))))) %>%
  unnest_wider(Anew, names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 8
      A   C_1   C_2   C_3     M Anew1 Anew2 Anew3
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     6     2
2     2     2     2     2     2     4     7     3
3     3     3     3     3     3     9     8     4
```

---

Or instead of doing `rowwise`, we may create a named `list` of functions and apply column wise with `across` (would be more efficient)

```
fns <- list(C_1 = function(x) x^2, C_2 = function(x) x + 5, 
      C_3 = function(x) x + 1)
dat %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("C_"), 
    ~ fns[[cur_column()]](.x), .names = "Anew{seq_along(.fn)}"))
```

-output

```
   A C_1 C_2 C_3 M Anew1 Anew2 Anew3
1 1   1   1   1 1     1     6     2
2 2   2   2   2 2     4     7     3
3 3   3   3   3 3     9     8     4
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'C_1' = 1:3, 'C_2' = 1:3, C_3 = 1:3, 'M' = 1:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`starts_with` must be used within a selecting function so we can write this.  `across` is also a selecting function so we could alternately use `across(M | starts_with('C_'))` in place of `select(...)` . `c_across` is also a selecting function but it does not preserve names.

```
dat %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Anew = list({function(x) c(x[1]^2, x[2] + 5, x[3] + 1)}
    (select(cur_data(), M, starts_with('C_'))))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest_wider(Anew, names_sep = "")
## # A tibble: 3 × 7
##       A   C_1   C_2     M AnewM AnewC_1 AnewC_2
##   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
## 1     1     1     1     1     1       6       2
## 2     2     2     2     2     4       7       3
## 3     3     3     3     3     9       8       4
```

Here `group_modify` would also work and allow the use of formula notation to specify an anonymous function.  The indexes in the anonymous function have been reordered to correspond to the order in the input.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  group_modify(~ cbind(.x, Anew = c(.x[3]^2, .x[1] + 5, .x[2] + 1))) %>%
  ungroup
## # A tibble: 3 × 7
##       A   C_1   C_2     M Anew.M Anew.C_1 Anew.C_2
##   <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1     1     1     1     1      1        6        2
## 2     2     2     2     2      4        7        3
## 3     3     3     3     3      9        8        4
```